# Read Emails from outlook mailbox

Tags: vbscript, outlook, scripting

Outlook product version : 16.0.1073020348

So I made an script to read emails and insert them into a DB.

The problem: The script is reading currently from my Inbox(red flag) and not from the shared mailbox(blue flag)

Desired Solution: Check the shared mailbox(blue flag)

[image: My Outlook App]

Currently my code looks something like this:

```
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
'PROBLEM HERE I GUESS
Set objFolder = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(6) 'Inbox

Set colItems = objFolder.Items

Set colFilteredItems = colItems.Restrict("[Unread]=true")

Set colFilteredItems = colFilteredItems.Restrict("[Subject] = SUBJECT")


For k = colFilteredItems.Count to 1 step -1 
    set objMessage  = colFilteredItems.Item(k)
    '....
next
```

Any help appreciated

Tried the method suggested by @josefZ , but keep struggling with it
1st try(failing on last line):

```
Set myRecipient = objNamespace.CreateRecipient("mailbox@mail.com")

myRecipient.Resolve

Set objFolder = objNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(myRecipient,olFolderInbox).Folders("Bandeja de Entrada")
```

[image: error wscript]

Comment: Apply [`GetSharedDefaultFolder` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getshareddefaultfolder) rather than `GetDefaultFolder` one?

Comment: @JosefZ tried but giving me some error, updated question can you check ?

Comment: @JosefZ nevermind solved rn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use `GetSharedDefaultFolder` or, since the delegate store is already opened in the profile, retrieve the delegate mailbox from the `Namespace.Stores` collection and use `Store.GetDefaultFolder` instead of `Namespace.GetDefaultFolder`.

Answer (score 0):

Like this is working:

```
Set myRecipient = objNamespace.CreateRecipient("mailbox@mail.com")

myRecipient.Resolve

Set objFolder = objNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(myRecipient,6) 'inbox
```